# Culling strings from a list that are substrings of other list elements

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, strings, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm bothered by [my answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56739019/10135377).

I'm pretty sure it's more efficient than the sort-and-cull implementations, but I'm having trouble expressing that in a way that I trust.

Also, it's rather convoluted by python standards.
Is there a way to express the same process more clearly, without pages of comments?

## The problem statement:

> Given a subject list of strings, make a list containing every element of the subject that isn't a substring of a different element of the subject.

## <del>Original</del> Current solution:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from typing import Dict, Generator, Iterable, List, Union

# Exploded is a recursive data type representing a culled list of strings as a tree of character-by-character common prefixes. The leaves are the non-common suffixes.
Exploded = None
Exploded = Dict[str, Union[Exploded, str]]

def explode(subject:typing.Iterable[str])->Exploded:
    heads_to_tails = dict()
    for s in subject:
        if s:
            head = s[0]
            tail = s[1:]
            if head in heads_to_tails:
                heads_to_tails[head].append(tail)
            else:
                heads_to_tails[head] = [tail]
    return {
        h: prune_or_follow(t)
        for (h, t) in heads_to_tails.items()
    }

def prune_or_follow(tails: List[str]) -> Union[Exploded, str]:
    if 1 < len(tails):
        return explode(tails)
    else: #we just assume it's not empty.
        return tails[0]

def implode(e: Exploded) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    for (head, continued) in e.items():
        if isinstance(continued, str):
            yield head + continued
        else:
            for tail in implode(continued):
                yield head + tail

def cull(subject: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    return list(implode(explode(subject)))

print(cull(['a','ab','ac','add']))
print(cull([ 'a boy ran' , 'green apples are worse' , 'a boy ran towards the mill' ,  ' this is another sentence ' , 'a boy ran towards the mill and fell']))
print(cull(['a', 'ab', 'ac', 'b', 'add']))
```

I know that it works **for the <del>two</del> three test cases**.

Comment: IMHO a lot of the code's perceived verbosity comes from the type hints. Formatting them with a little bit of well placed whitespace here and there might already lead to code that looks friendlier.

Comment: As a quick comment: using typing is not a perfect substitute for documentation: the logic is non-trivial and deserves to be explained in a comment. It looks like you are building some kind of Trie. Is it correct ?

Comment: Ok, since nobody had left any answers yet, i've edited the question to reflect what the two of you have mentioned so far.

Comment: This doesn't work.  `print(cull(['a', 'ab', 'ac', 'b', 'add']))` outputs `['add', 'b']`.  `groupby()` does _not_ sort it's input, so when the dictionary comprehension in `explode()` gets to 'add', it overwrites the entry for 'a' that was created when processing `['a', 'ab', 'ac'].

Comment: mother f*er. I spent like five minutes _after_ confirming the bug with your input trying to figure out _why_ `groupby` _would_ sort, and why we'd care if it did. This isn't even the first time I've been hit by this. In absolute seriousness, who in hell publishes a function like that to a public library?

Comment: Ok, fixed. In some ways I guess this is a little easier to read. In retrospect, I think part of what was opaque about the functional-style solution was that I was splitting off the heads prior to grouping.

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter The non-sorting behaviour is stated explicitly in the documentation. It collapses adjacent identical values. This works for any iterable, even infinite ones. It is a design choice by the Python developers. If you want the groups of the sorted data, they provide the `sorted` builtin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All in all this looks good already.

A few tips:

## `continue`

If you change the test in `explode` from `if s:` to

```
if not s:
    continue
```

You can save a level of indentation for the rest of the loop

## `collections.defaultdict`

checking whether a key is in a dict, and adding it if it isn't is why there is `collections.defaultdict` which can simplify `explode` a lot:

```
def explode(subject: Iterable[str]) -> Exploded:
    heads_to_tails = defaultdict(list)
    for s in subject:
        if not s:
            continue
        heads_to_tails[s[0]].append(s[1:])
    return {h: prune_or_follow(t) for (h, t) in heads_to_tails.items()}
```

## tuple unpacking

A matter of style, but in most situations where you use `my_list[0]` and `my_list[1:]`, you can use tuple unpacking. You can use this in `prune_or_follow`

```
def prune_or_follow(tails: List[str]) -> Union[Exploded, str]:
    start, *rest = tails
    if rest:
        return explode(tails)
    else:  
        return start
```

Whether this is more clear is a matter of taste.

This tuple unpacking does not work as clean in `explode` because it converts the string into a list of 1-character strings.

## `Exploded`

You can use a string in `typing` so you can do:

```
Exploded = Dict[str, Union["Exploded", str]]
```

without the `Exploded = None`

## `cull` typing

cull can accept any iterable. For the result, I don't think the order of strings is important, so there is no need to limit you to a `list`. The signature can then be `def cull(subject: Iterable[str]) -> Collection[str]:`. Whether you return a list or a set is a matter of implementation.

If the result is just used for iteration, you can even forgo the `list` call, and just return the `implode` generator, and let the caller decide whether he needs in in a list, set or whatever data structure he wants.

## implode

now you use `e` as argument name. One-letter variable names are unclear in general, and to be avoided most of the time*. Since it is a kind of a tree, I would change this variable.

A slightly different take in `implode` which doesn't use string concatenation but tuple unpacking:

```
def implode(tree: Exploded, previous=()) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    for root, branches in tree.items():
        if isinstance(branches, str):
            yield "".join((*previous, root, *branches))
        else:
            yield from implode(branches, *previous, root)
```

or equivalently:

```
def implode(tree: Exploded, previous=()) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    for root, branches in tree.items():
        if isinstance(branches, str):
            yield "".join((*previous, root, *branches))
        else:
            yield from implode(branches, (*previous, root))
```

The choice between your version and this is a matter of taste, but I wanted to present the different possibilities.

Another variation, is using `try-except ArgumentError` instead of the `isinstance`:

```
def implode_except(tree: Exploded, previous=()) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    for root, branches in tree.items():
        try:
            yield from implode(branches, (*previous, root))
        except AttributeError:
            yield "".join((*previous, root, *branches))
```

'* I find `i`, `j` etc acceptable for a counter or index, and `x` and `y` for coordinates, but in general I try not to use one-letter variable names.

Comment: Thanks; i've implemented most of this over at the parent question!